# Path tool not working correctly?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to make the edges of the selected path tool narrower and more pointed. But for some reason it is not scaling at the ends and i have no idea. If anyone can help then please do. [image].I am adding a image for your refence.

Comment: It's Alt S to change the radius, you can also change it in the N panel > Item > Radius, but Nurbs Path doesn't exactly work like Bezier, it looks like you need to scale several vertices

Comment: yes, and thank you so much for your help @moonboots

Answer (score 1):

It's <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to change the radius, you can also change it in the *N panel > Item > Radius*, but Nurbs Path doesn't exactly work like Bezier, it looks like you need to scale several vertices.